# calculate the difference in days using Date::Manip in perl

Tags: perl, date

The code below only expresses the difference in months and days like so:

0:2:0:5:0:0:0

So it works, but I want to know the total number of days given that $ADDate can vary quite a bit. Hopefully this is simple, and I just completely missed how to do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Date::Manip 6.42;

my $ADDate = "20131211000820.0Z";
my $var;
my @val;
my $diff;

calc_period($ADDate = "20131211000820.0Z");

sub calc_period
{
$ADDate =~ s/^([\d][\d][\d][\d])([\d][\d])([\d][\d])/$1-$2-$3/gs;
$ADDate =~ s/.........$//gs;
$today = ParseDate("today");

$beginning = ParseDate($ADDate);
$end = ParseDate($today);
$delta = DateCalc($beginning,$end,\$err,1);

#$delta =~ s/([\d+][:][\d+]):.*$/$1/gs;


print "$delta\n";
print "$ADDate\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Date::Manip, but I think another way to do this is to use [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Time-Piece-1.27/Piece.pm) to parse your string and do whatever you like with that since [taking the difference of two Time::Piece object returns a Time::Seconds object](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Time-Piece-1.27/Piece.pm#Date_Calculations).

The following example will show the difference of the current time and the hardcoded time and show it in days.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $d = "20131211000820.0Z";

my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($d, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S.0Z");
my $now = Time::Piece->localtime();

my $diff = Time::Seconds->new($now - $t);

print $diff->days, "\n";
```

Comment: Also, `Time::Piece` has been a core module since version 10 of Perl 5, and shouldn't need installing.

Answer (score 1):

NigoroJr has already given you an answer.  However, just as an FYI, the following is how I would clean up the code you originally provided:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Date::Manip 6.42;

use strict;
use warnings;

calc_period("20131211000820.0Z");

sub calc_period {
    my $date = shift;
    $date =~ s/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2}).*/$1-$2-$3/;

    my $beginning = ParseDate($date);
    my $end = ParseDate("today");
    my $delta = DateCalc($beginning, $end, \my $err, 1);

    #$delta =~ s/([\d+][:][\d+]):.*$/$1/gs;

    print "$delta\n";
    print "$date\n";
}
```

Biggest differences being the proper use of a function and scoped variables, and a simplification of your regex.

I was unable to find a clean way to get Date::Manip to output a strict delta in days though, so the other module is the way to go.

Comment: I can still learn from that.  It's always great to learn how to tighten up code a bit better, thanks!